Syntax error in mdx file when running docusaurus-mdx-checker
I run the check
npx docusaurus-mdx-checker

and got the error
Error while compiling file ../docs/concepts/data_versioning.mdx (Line=157 Column=2)
Details: Could not parse expression with acorn

this is the 157
{@codeBlock: TestEpochManager.defineCustomEpochPolicy}

What should I Change that it can compile?

Is that the full error?

@Evert yes, I am doing npx docusaurus-mdx-checker.
